Probability Theory - Picking a card

We have a pack of 12 red cards (labeled 1-12) and 12 blue cards (labeled 1-12) and we randomly remove 2 cards from the blue cards deck and shuffle all the remaining 22 cards. A card is picked at random and it is found out to be a 3. What is the probability it is blue?

I can't find the answer online, but I worked it out and got a probability of $\frac{5}{11}$. I was wondering, since we already know it is a 3, why can't the probability of it being blue be $\frac{1}{2}$?
And is there any shortcut to find the solution faster?
My working:
$$\Pr(B/3) = \frac{\Pr(B \cap 3)}{\Pr(3)}$$
$$\Pr(B \cap 3) = \Pr(3B/3B \text{ wasn't removed})\times\Pr(3B\text{ wasn't removed}) = \frac{1}{22}\times\frac{11}{12}\times\frac{10}{11}$$
$$\Pr(3) = \Pr(B \cap 3) + \Pr(R \cap 3) = \frac{5}{132} + \frac{1}{22} = \frac{11}{132}$$
$$\Pr(B/3) = \frac{5/132}{11/132} = \frac{5}{11}$$

Clearly the fact that it’s a $3$ is irrelevant… all values are equivalent.  You may as well ask what the probability is that you drew a blue card.  And that’s obviously $10/22=5/11$.

There's the shortest shortcut  !

I still don't understand how we can just disregard the fact 3 was picked. Are you telling me that P(getting blue | 3 was picked) = P(getting blue)? How does that work?

The reason that you are confused is because your intuition has not yet developed fully, with respect to conditional probability problems.  The only way remedy that I know of is to attack many, many such problems.  If you have a math professor recommend the right book, that contains $~50~$ such problems, and you attack/conquer these problems, then you will no longer be confused about this problem.

Thank you! Do you have any online resource recommendations for such problems?

@ShsTht It is due to exchangeablity of the rank.  The probability that the card is blue given that it is a 3 is the same as the probability that the card is blue given that it is a 1, et cetera. $$\mathsf P(B\mid C=1)=\mathsf P(B\mid C=2)=\mathsf P(B\mid C=3) = \ldots=\mathsf P(B\mid C=12)$$

The symmetry is broken by removing 2 cards from the blue suit before picking the 3 card from the deck.
So that card was either picked from a deck containing two 3 cards, or from a deck containing only the red 3.  That is that if the blue 3 was removed, then the 3 you drew could not be blue (obviously).
Therefore, making it slightly more likely than not that the 3 which you picked was red.
Thus, the answer is $5/11$ as you correctly calculated.

Here's my method:
Let $T$ be the event that we picked a 3.  Let $R$ be the event that the blue 3 was removed.  Let $B$ be the event that we picked a blue card.
$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B\mid T)&= \dfrac{\mathsf P(B, T)}{\mathsf P(T)}\\ &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(R)\mathsf P(B,T\mid R)+\mathsf P(R^\complement)\mathsf P(B,T\mid R^\complement)}{\mathsf P(R)\mathsf P(T\mid R)+\mathsf P(R^\complement)\mathsf P(T\mid R^\complement)}\\&=\dfrac{(2/12)(0/22)+(10/12)(1/22)}{(2/12)(1/22)+(10/12)(2/22)}\\&=\dfrac{5}{11}\end{align}$

And as pointed out in the comments, the event of the card being blue is independent of the rank of the card.   There is one red and one blue card for each of the twelve ranks, so the evaluation would be the same reguardless of which rank you had picked.   Thus the answer is just the probability that the picked card is blue: $$\mathsf P(B\mid T)=\mathsf P(B)=10/22$$
